# Excel VBA Copy and Paste Specific # of Rows and New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a Master Sheet called `ContactsforEmails` from this workbook, I am copying the header into every new workbook.

Then, I am copying and pasting every 40 rows starting at `A2` until `I` column. The new workbook is saved and closed. Then I want to loop back create another new Workbook name it "EmailList(next number)" and so copy the next 40. Then run till the next cell in the `A` column is blank.

I have managed to copy the header,save as a new document,and copy the first 40.
I haven't figured out how to make it loop correctly, I suspect it is with *DoUntil* loop and *Offset*. But I am hoping someone more advanced in this can advise.

The error I run into is "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range."

Here is my attempt:

```
'Copy Header
   Range("A1").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Rows("1:1").EntireRow.AutoFit

'Save File As New Name
   Dim fpath As String
   Dim fcount As Integer
   Dim fname As String
   Do While Len(Dir(fpath & fname)) <> 0
     fpath = "C:\Users\Path\"
     fcount = fcount + 1
     fname = "EmailList" & fcount & ".xlsx"
   Loop
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & fname
'Copy and Paste 40
  Windows("ContactsForEmails.xlsx").Activate
    Dim fcopy As Range
    Set fcopy = Range("A2:H41")
    fcopy.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(fname).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Do Until IsEmpty(fcopy)
     fcopy.Offset(40, 0).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Windows(fname).Activate
     Range("A2").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     ActiveWorkbook.Save
     ActiveWorkbook.Close
   Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: And what's going wrong with your attempts? How does the actual result differ from what you want/expect to happen?

Comment: I was working on this again. Changed my code and got the first 2 parts to work. What is wrong w my attempts now is that I can't get it to go back and copy the next 40 rows onto a new workbook. I suspect I am on the right track but the _DoUntil_ loop is placed in the wrong area. Thank you for asking.